# Can chrome.tabs.executeScript() be called from within a content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried to look for this in the chrome documentation but I didn't see anything, especially in the "Security" section in the chrome.tabs documentation. The typical approach in examples I've seen is to send a message to the background page. The background page then calls chrome.tabs.executeScript(). If I can do it from the content script that would be a little easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content scripts cannot call any Chrome API methods except couple from `chrome.extension.*` package.

Unless you are doing this to save content script filesize, why not just have that code you are planning to execute in a content script from the beginning?

Comment: How do you know this? Is it documented somewhere, or did you just learn from trial & error?

Comment: @Robert Know that scripts cannot call api? It is stated here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html You can also do `console.log(chrome)` from a content script to see what's available.